# Extra space in Theorems', Lemmas', etc. title

Tags: theorems, amsthm

I am using the following command to include a title (e.g. a citation) as the title of my lemma,

```
\begin{lemma}[\cite{Mieghem11}]
```

> `This is my lemma ...`

```
\end{lemma}
```

but I'm getting an extra space there,

[image]

I'm using amsthm package with IEEEtran.cls

```
\documentclass[10pt, twocolumn, twoside, journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, color, enumerate, amsthm, graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz, subcaption, cite}
\usepackage{color, xcolor, soul, bm}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\begin{document}
    \begin{lemma}[\cite{Mieghem11}]\label{lem: max singular}
        This is my lemma ...
    \end{lemma}
\end{document}
```

This also happens for definitions,

[image]

Comment: Maybe try `{\cite{Mieghem11}}` (with the outer braces)?

Comment: @Bernard That removes the parantheses.

Comment: `\begin{lemma}{\cite{Mieghem11}}` would remove parentheses, but I think `\begin{lemma}[{\cite{Mieghem11}}]` would leave them.

Comment: I meant the latter solution.

Comment: @Teepeemm Yes, but the second command still keeps the extra space :(

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Please, make a minimal example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.

Comment: @egreg Just updated.

Comment: I see no extra space.

Comment: @egreg This also happens for definitions (see the update).

Comment: I don't get problem here.

Comment: @Mohammad The example is not complete: from the picture it is apparent you're using also `hyperref` and maybe other packages that *might* redefine `\cite`.

Comment: @egreg Yes. Sorry I forgot to include them in the question. I've removed them but the problem still exists.

Comment: Now I can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Remove `\usepackage{cite}`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161848/how-to-remove-white-space-before-reference

Comment: @egreg But removing cite package causes weird stuff like [3]-[6] is converted to [3], [4], [5], [6] :(